# How do I install the empathy smilies (from maverick) in Pidgin?

Tags: gnome, empathy, pidgin

How do I install the empathy smilies (from maverick) in Pidgin? I really like the look of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually create a smiley plugin pack for pidgin using the empathy smilies. It didn't tak long and worked out great.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the new Ubuntu speech-bubble emoticons, then try this:

http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/d0od/~3/VRw0IcDI77w/

Answer (score 1):

I found grait collection of Pidgin artworks - smiles, status icons, etc. Its simple! Go to http://www.deviantart.com/ and search for "pidgin". There are meny ready-to-use packs!